# Get value as Json format itself in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have an html inpit field like this

```
       <input type="hidden" value="[{"id":3,"menu_name":"testdata1","table_name":"tbl_testdata1","category_name":"networking"},{"id":5,"menu_name":"newbook","table_name":"tbl_newbook1","category_name":"networking"},{"id":4,"menu_name":"books","table_name":"tbl_books","category_name":"system"}]" id="resultdata" name="resultdata">
```

I tried to fetch value of this filed using:

```
$(function() {  
          var data=$('#resultdata').val();


        var categories = {},
        groupBy = "category_name",
        ul = $('<ul id="dropdown-menu">');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
            if (!categories[data[i][groupBy]])
                categories[data[i][groupBy]] = [];
            categories[data[i][groupBy]].push(data[i]);
        };

        for (key in categories) 
        {
            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            {
                var li = $('<li>').text(key);
                if (categories[key].length)
                {
                    var ul_inner = $('<ul>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < categories[key].length; i++) 
                    {
                        $('<li>').html(categories[key][i].menu_name + ', ' + categories[key][i].id).appendTo(ul_inner);
                    }
                    li.append(ul_inner);
                }
                li.appendTo('#tree1');
            }
        }                           
        $('#tree1').treed();
        });
```

I'm trying to append this result to  but it is giving result as undefined. I need the hidden input filed value in json format itself. How is it possible ?

Comment: I dont think its possible to have the value of the input tag a JSON object.

Comment: Change double quotes for value to single quote!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your double quotes("). Change `value=""` to `value=''` and it should work just fine.

Because with your current input your value looks like `value="[{"id"` then you have a lot of invalid data in your input

**Demo**

```js
var data = $('#resultdata').val();

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value='[{" id ":3,"menu_name ":"testdata1 ","table_name ":"tbl_testdata1 ","category_name ":"networking "},{"id ":5,"menu_name ":"newbook ","table_name ":"tbl_newbook1 ","category_name ":"networking "},{"id ":4,"menu_name ":"books","table_name ":"tbl_books ","category_name ":"system "}]' id="resultdata" name="resultdata">
```

Comment: I tried with single quotes.it will alert the data in json format.I hard coded the same data and tried that will also work. but when i am append the same data it will show undefined